# Fix Anchor link to the bottom of card

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using a card which has some text in it, However the "Explore" link needs to be fixed to the bottom of the card irrespective of the size of the text above.
Can this be achieved without using bootstrap classes.

My Card preview:

[![1]][1]

Card code:

```
<div class="ibm-col-12-3 card">
  <div class="ibm-card mobileFlex ibm-no-border">
    <div class="ibm
```

```css
.card{
border-style:solid;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
                <div class="ibm-card mobileFlex ibm-no-border">
                    <div class="ibm-card__image">
                        <img id="use-case-img-3" src="" alt="card_3" width="300" height="170" class="ibm-resize"></div>
                    <div class="ibm-card__content">
                        <p id="use-case-title-3" class="cardTitle">title of the page </p>
                        <p id="use-case-sub-title-3" class="cardSubtitle">sub title of the page</p>
                        <p class="ibm-ind-link">
                            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadUseCasePage('2')" class="ibm-forward-link ibm-light"><span class="ucExplore">Explore</span></a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

-card__image">

Explore

Comment: _"Can this be achieved without using bootstrap classes."_ - Sure. What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: can u bring a  css code ? any way you can use fixed-height in ```ibm-card__content``` and use flex-box or css grid or just contain the title and sub title  with fixed height div and use ```line-clamp``` for text

Comment: @Andreas have tried css position: absolute; bottom: 0px;  Not working

Comment: @moufed for my app card size is dynamic, the secondary and primary data are not mandatory.

Comment: Have provided the solution, does this help. I tried first then shared the same. For me it works fine. :)

Comment: It would be great if you could tell the snippet to show the "Card preview".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to solve the problem.

```css
.card{
border-style:solid;
height:200px;
}

.ibm-card{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.ibm-card__content{
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ibm-ind-link{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="card">
    <div class="ibm-card mobileFlex ibm-no-border">
      <div class="ibm-card__image">
        <img id="use-case-img-3" src="" alt="card_3" width="300" height="170" class="ibm-resize"></div>
      <div class="ibm-card__content">
        <div class="content">
          <p id="use-case-title-3" class="cardTitle">title of the page </p>
          <p id="use-case-sub-title-3" class="cardSubtitle">sub title of the page</p>
        </div>

        <p class="ibm-ind-link">
          <a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadUseCasePage('2')" class="ibm-forward-link ibm-light">
            <span class="ucExplore">Explore</span></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```